# two view in the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am working with asp.net MVC2, I'm new in development. net
I have a view that contains 2 dropdownlist and a button, I want when I click the button, another view is displayed, I want both to appear on the same page

Answer (score 0):

There is two way you can implement this

1) With Complete post back you can use Html.RenderAction or load the partial view. You can use some flag to differentiate between the first time page load and post back

2) You can use the jquery AJAX and call the controller action of another View and get the content and write it to the div of the page .

Please do some research work on both and I think you can get the result as you want.